# Unable to receive mail through GAE application

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine

I have this Google App Engine application **"demo****"** and version **"mail"** through which I am trying to read mails. 
I went through the GAE link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving

Exactly followed all the steps mentioned in the link.
My web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>emailhandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.selfservice.ReceiveEmailServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>emailhandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I have this in my appengine-web.xml:

```
<inbound-services>
    <service>mail</service>
</inbound-services>
```

In the GAE console, under application settings, I could find the "Incoming mail" under the configured services also.

[image: Configured_services]

I am trying to send mail to the application using the format **"test@demo****.appspotmail.com"**. But the mail does not deliver. It says "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:".

Yet the application does not show any logs. What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you are not trying to run this on the devserver (which doesn't do  mail) the only difference in your configuration i can see is that the docs configure `<web-resource-name>mail</web-resource-name>` in the security constraint, web-resource-collection.

Comment: Doesn't help either konqi. Once I try sending mail, I get the failure message stating "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently".

Comment: Where's the message coming from? Is it an email or does the message appear in the logs? 'Delivery failed permanently' is usually a problem in the delivery process and not at send time. Maybe try a few different email services? Also double check whether your appid.appspotmail.com address is correct. Maybe there is a typo or an extra character from copying it in from somewhere else. I use inbound email in this project (https://github.com/konqi/gmail-gateway/) maybe that helps.